# How do I mock Mongoose calls without mocking the callback logic in exec?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mocking, sinon

I've written a test against my *itemService* function `getItemsForUser` to assert on the Items returned from a Mongoose `find` call. However, my test is currently passing regardless of the user object passed in because it mocks out the whole callback passed to `exec`.

My question is, how can I mock out only the Items returned by the `find` and `populate` but not skip the rest of the logic, so that the test does actually call `doUsersContainUser`?

*itemService.js*

```
const Item = require('../models/item');

exports.getItemsForUser= function(user, cb)
{
    Item.find({}).populate('users').exec(function (err, itemList)
    {
        if (err) { throw next(err) }
        else {
            cb(null, itemList.filter(i=> doUsersContainUser(i, user._id));
        }
    });
};

function doUsersContainUser(item, userId) {
    return item.users.some(u => hasValue(u, 'user', userId))
}
```

*item.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema );
```

*itemServiceTest.js*

```
it('should return all items for user', function () {
    const allItems = itemsData.allItemsPopulated();
    const user = { id: 10001 };

    sinon.mock(Item).expects('find')
        .chain('populate', 'users')
        .chain('exec')
        .returns(null, allItems);

    itemService.getItemsForUser(user, function(err, result) {
        assert.strictEqual(result, allItems);
    });
});
```

I am using sinon-mongoose for the chained mongoose calls.

Comment: How did you `require` `doUsersContainUser` function and `Item`? Please provide the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 Included the code now